# Similar Javascript and python code does not give same result

Tags: javascript, python

I have a problem, I have 2 scripts one is in javascript and one is python.
I want to use python to generate the value so I tried to rewrite javascript code to python
but the output is not the same and I can't seem to figure out what values are incorrect!
Any help is appreciated
I am very bad at javascript, but I have a basic/decent understanding of python.

My javascript Code:

```js
<html><head><script type="text/javascript"><!--
function leastFactor(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;
 if (typeof phantom !== 'undefined') return 'phantom';
 if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) return 'node';
 if (n==0) return 0;
 if (n%1 || n*n<2) return 1;
 if (n%2==0) return 2;
 if (n%3==0) return 3;
 if (n%5==0) return 5;
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
  if (n%i==0)      return i;
  if (n%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
  if (n%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
  if (n%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
  if (n%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
  if (n%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
  if (n%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
  if (n%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
 }
 return n;
}
function go() {
 var p=2998236216354; var s=1750047503; var n;
if ((s >> 15) & 1)/*
else p-=
*/p+= 80068513*
16; else /*
else p-=
*/p-=
60707526*/*
*13;
*/16;/*
p+= */if ((s >> 7) & 1)/*
else p-=
*/p+=/*
else p-=
*/116987388* 8; else 
p-= 172213350*/*
else p-=
*/8;if ((s >> 2) & 1)/*
*13;
*/p+=/*
p+= */54228284*/* 120886108*
*/5;/*
*13;
*/else /*
p+= */p-= 542313502*/* 120886108*
*/3;/*
*13;
*/if ((s >> 10) & 1) p+=66991160*/* 120886108*
*/13;else /*
p+= */p-=
158065083*
11;if ((s >> 2) & 1)/*
else p-=
*/p+=311247981*/*
*13;
*/5;/*
*13;
*/else /*
else p-=
*/p-=
376627923* 3; p-=910005807;
 n=leastFactor(p);
{ document.cookie="RNKEY="+n+"*"+p/n+":"+s+":3025753160:1";
}
}
//--></script></head>
<body onload="go()">
Loading ...
</body>
</html>
```

My Python Code:

```js
import math
 
def least_factor(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 0;
 
  if n % 1 or n * n < 2: return 1
  if n % 2 == 0: return 2
  if n % 3 == 0: return 3
  if n % 5 == 0: return 5
 
  m = math.sqrt(n)
 
  for i in range(7, int(m + 1), 30):
    if n % i == 0: return i
    if n % (i + 4): return i + 4
    if n % (i + 6): return i + 6
    if n % (i + 10): return i + 10
    if n % (i + 12): return i + 12
    if n % (i + 16): return i + 16
    if n % (i + 22): return i + 22
    if n % (i + 24): return i + 24

  return n
 
def go():
  p = 2998236216354
  s = 1750047503
  n = None
  
  if (s >> 15) & 1: p += 80068513 * 16
  else: p -= 60707526 * 16
 
  if (s >> 7) & 1: p += 116987388 * 8
  else: p -= 172213350 * 8
 
  if (s >> 2) & 1: p += 54228284 * 5
  else: p -= 542313502 * 3
 
  if (s >> 10) & 1: p += 66991160 * 13
  else: p -= 158065083 * 11
 
  if (s >> 2) & 1: p += 311247981  * 5
  else: p -= 376627923 * 3
 
  p -= 910005807
  n = least_factor(p)
 
  return f'RNKEY={n}*{p / n}:{s}:3025753160:1'
 
print(go())
```

The output on javascript is:
RNKEY=1691507*1771981:1750047503:3025753160:1

But on Python the output is:
RNKEY=11*272483478669.72726:1750047503:3025753160:1

Can someone help me understand where in my python code I am giving the wrong values?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At which part of this sequence of mathematical operations do the results start to diverge?

Comment: JavaScript: `if (n%(i+4)==0) ...`, Python: `if n % (i + 4):` (and so on). One is the opposite of the other.

Comment: One of your problems is that you're using a floating point variable on python for at least one value!

Answer (score 1):

In your Python code, in the for loop, you have a line

```
if n % (i + 4): return i + 4
```

This if condition is true if `n % (i+4)` is *not* equal to 0, so if n is *not* divisible by i+4. This is the opposite of what you want, and the opposite of what your JavaScript code does.

It should be, for example,

```
if not n % (i + 4): return i + 4
```